# Fanpage tab redirect to app canvas

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-canvas, facebook-page

We are creating a canvas app and would like to add directly to my fanpage.

There are 2 ways that I'm not sure about how to take the user to the app's fanpage.

First would be to create a tab and add it in the fanpage.
On this tab would have some text and a call-to-action to redirect to app canvas.

Would create a second tab and add it in the fanpage only with a redirect to take the user directly to the fanpage of the app.

Is there any documentation specific to this practice or some restriction to redirect the tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if your app was loaded inside a page tab, parse the [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/) server-side and look if there is [a page-id set](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/).

If so, answer that request with a minimal HTML document containing not much more than a piece of JavaScript code to redirect inside the top window instance, like this:

```
top.location.href = "https://apps.facebook.com/yourappsnamespace";
```

There should be no restrictions on that – Facebook is only worried about automatically redirecting users away from Facebook (to outside domains), but since you are redirecting to a canvas app, they stay on their site.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) clearly state:

> We do not accept Canvas pages that redirect to Page Tabs, or vice
>   versa.